# Running Pytest on files mentioned in a Github Pull Request using Cloud Build Trigger

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, yaml, pytest, google-cloud-build

I have a Cloud Build trigger which runs only when a new Pull Request is created on master branch of a Github repo.

However, right now, pytest is running on the whole repo, while I require pytest to be run only on files that have been created/edited in the Pull Request.

My cloudbuild file is as follows:

```
#Testing
steps:
- name: 'python:3.7'
  id: Testing
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
    - '-c'
    - |
       pip install --upgrade pip \
       && pip install -r requirements.txt \
       && pytest **/test_*.py
```

Any idea how to implement this?

Comment: You want run only **tests that have changed** or you want to run only tests **related to files that have changed**?

Comment: I want to run only the tests which have been modified/created in the Pull Request.

Comment: @AbhinavDhiman is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that Cloud Build does not expose the list of modified files in pull requests, but as a workaround you can use Github's webhooks.

1. Get the “_PULL_REQUEST_ID” in cloud build using substitution process as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/use-bash-and-bindings-in-substitutions#payload_bindings)
   `_PULL_REQUEST_ID $(pull_request.pull_request.id)`
2. Use the above pull request id received in the substitution process in github rest api and get the list of modified/created files.

   a) To know how this api works refer [api link](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests-files).

   b) How to use rest api refer [rest link](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-rest-api).

   c) Refer to example code at github [github link](https://github.community/t/get-list-of-files-on-pull-request-merge/17226).

   Update GITHUB_REPOSITORY to $REPO_NAME as per [doc](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values) and update github.event.pull_request.number to the number received in step 1

   `URL="https://api.github.com/repos/${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}/pulls/${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}/files"
   FILES=$(curl -s -X GET -G $URL | jq -r '.[] | .filename')
   echo “$FILES” > modified.txt`
3. As per above example code, list of files will be saved to modified.txt. As you get the list of modified/created files you can perform tests on those by getting the file names from modified.txt by using bash while loops or python loop.